# unable to link css file in denjucks template file

Tags: nunjucks, deno

I am using deno and denjucks as templating engine. in template .html file header section, I am linking my external css file but failed. the code-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='../static/style.css'>
```

the file format is -

```
main
 static
  style.css
 templates
  index.html
```

Bootstrap link is working but custom css link is not working. Please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: Show your server code.

Comment: import denjucks from "https://deno.land/x/denjucks/mod.js";

denjucks.configure("templates", { autoescape: true });


const users = db.collection("users");
export default {
  main(context: any) {
    context.response.body = denjucks.render(
      "index.html",
      { txt: " This is my World" },
    );
  }                                                                                                                     This is the server code from where template is calling.

Comment: Update your answer with the code, thanks :)

Comment: If I use Flask and Jinja2, I can do something like this:

<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
How do I do something like this with denjucks, deno and oak ? Or lets say what is the standard approach in denjucks to tell the index.html which folders it should use to look for css, js & img files?

Comment: Update your function with your server code, and I'll give you the answer, without knowing what you have, it's hard to tell.